# Kernel's not found error in arch

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, archlinux

I run this command:

```
sudo dkms autoinstall -k 3.11.6-1-ARCH
```

and have error:

```
Error! echo
Your kernel headers for kernel 3.11.6-1-ARCH cannot be found at
/usr/lib/modules/3.11.6-1-ARCH/build or /usr/lib/modules/3.11.6-1-ARCH/source.
Error! echo
Your kernel headers for kernel 3.11.6-1-ARCH cannot be found at
/usr/lib/modules/3.11.6-1-ARCH/build or /usr/lib/modules/3.11.6-1-ARCH/source.
```

what should I do?

Comment: Try `linux-headers-kirkwood`.

Comment: Can you say more. What is it: linux-headers-kirkwood?

Comment: It says "command not" found. I've searched in repos, but it's also "command not found".

Comment: Please look how to install kernel at http://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=3935

Answer (score 7):

Do you actually have kernel headers for the stock repo kernel installed? They're not installed by default, so unless you explicitly did, you probably don't. Try running:

```
pacman -Sy linux-headers
```

and see what happens.

Also, does the kernel version you have match with what you're trying to run against it? If the above doesn't fix the problem, please post the output of

```
uname -a
```

Comment: **Warning**: When installing packages in Arch, avoid refreshing the package list without [upgrading the system](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman) (for example, when a [package is no longer found](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman) in the official repositories). In practice, do **not** run `pacman -Sy package_name` instead of `pacman -Syu package_name`, as this could lead to dependency issues. See [System maintenance#Partial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance) upgrades are unsupported and [BBS#89328](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=89328).